# Optimizing push and pop functions

Tags: c++, .net, optimization, queue, c++-cli

I have two threads; one calls `Push()` and the other calls `Pop()`. The problem I have is when `Push()` is called at a fast rate (say 100fps) then `Pop()` cannot keep up with the speed and the program crashes. At a lower frame rate (say 10fps) there is no problem. Is there anything I can do to optimize this piece of code ?

```
void AcqCache::Push(FrameData& frameData)
{
    // If cache not idle - wait
    Monitor::Enter(m_cacheLock);
    try
    {
        m_frameInfoBuffer[(frameData.GetFrameInfo().FrameNr - 1) % m_acqBuffer->BufferSize] = frameData;

        // Unlock processing thread
        m_frameDataCache->Push(frameData);
        Monitor::Pulse(m_cacheLock);
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor::Exit(m_cacheLock);
    }
}

void AcqCache::Pop()
{
    FrameData frData;
    while (m_processFrameRunning)
    {
        // If cache not idle - wait
        Monitor::Enter(m_cacheLock);
        try
        {
            Monitor::Wait(m_cacheLock);

            while (!m_frameDataCache->IsEmpty())
            {
                if (!m_processFrameRunning)
                    break;

                frData = std::move(m_frameDataCache->Pop());
                m_acqBuffer->CacheUsage = (int)m_frameDataCache->Count();
                // Add frame to frame stack
                m_acqBuffer->AddFrame(frData);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor::Exit(m_cacheLock);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: That sounds like a logic error, not an optimization problem.

Comment: What do `Monitor:: Wait / Enter / Pulse / Exit` do?